# sending http request to apache through a python script

Tags: python, httprequest

All,

How do we send a http request through a python script.which will login and in turn call another link?

Thanks.

Comment: this question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893119/python-script-to-login-to-a-url -- there's a much more detailed answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)? [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) may also be worth looking at as it is a slightly higher level interface.

Comment: Thanks all i found this  import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
200 OK
>>> data1 = r1.read()
>>> conn.request("GET", "/parrot.spam")
>>> r2 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r2.status, r2.reason
404 Not Found
>>> data2 = r2.read()
>>> conn.close() in the link.....I think it wud suffice for now.....

Comment: @Hulk: That comment is part of the question. You own the question.  You can update the question with additional information.  Please update the question and delete this silly comment.

Answer (score 1):

I find that [Urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) suffices in most cases.   It has great support for passwords, authentication and cookies.  Cookielib might help too.